# Chrome how to save css from developer tools without disabled styles

Tags: css, google-chrome

Is there any possibility to save css (as file) from developer tools without disabled styles? I found plugin for Chrome ([plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/css-remove-and-combine/cdfmaaeapjmacolkojefhfollmphonoh)) but unfortunately it's not working for me (it doesn't see any disabled styles).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: [SnappySnippet](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/snappysnippet/blfngdefapoapkcdibbdkigpeaffgcil)

Tell me if worked for you.